# Using buttons in excel to set filters automatically in a pivot table

Tags: excel, button, filter, pivot-table

Is there a fast macro that could automatically set filters in a pivot table for me if I were to press a form control button in excel? I don't have any experience with vba and macros and I tried recording one but it errors when one of the pivots isn't set to the same filters as it was originally set to when I recorded the macro.

Here's the code for it:

```
    Sub Filter_Foot()
'
' Filter_Foot Macro
'

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable3").PivotFields("MD").CurrentPage = "(All)"
    With ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable3").PivotFields("MD")
        .PivotItems("Name 1").Visible = False
        .PivotItems("Name 2").Visible = False
        .PivotItems("Name 3").Visible = False
        .PivotItems("Name 4").Visible = False
        .PivotItems("Name 5").Visible = False
        .PivotItems("Name 6").Visible = False
        .PivotItems("Name 7").Visible = False
        .PivotItems("Name 8").Visible = False
        .PivotItems("Name 9").Visible = False
        .PivotItems("Name 10").Visible = False
        .PivotItems("Name 11").Visible = False
        .PivotItems("Name 12").Visible = False
        .PivotItems("Name 13").Visible = False
        .PivotItems("Name 14").Visible = False
        .PivotItems("Name 15").Visible = False
        .PivotItems("Name 16").Visible = False
        .PivotItems("Name 17").Visible = False
        .PivotItems("Name 18").Visible = False
        .PivotItems("Name 19").Visible = False
        .PivotItems("Name 20").Visible = False
        .PivotItems("Name 21").Visible = False
        .PivotItems("(blank)").Visible = False
    End With
    ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable2").PivotFields("MD").CurrentPage = "(All)"
    With ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable2").PivotFields("MD")
        .PivotItems("Name 1").Visible = False
        .PivotItems("Name 2").Visible = False
        .PivotItems("Name 3").Visible = False
        .PivotItems("Name 4").Visible = False
        .PivotItems("Name 5").Visible = False
        .PivotItems("Name 6").Visible = False
        .PivotItems("Name 7").Visible = False
        .PivotItems("Name 8").Visible = False
        .PivotItems("Name 9").Visible = False
        .PivotItems("Name 10").Visible = False
        .PivotItems("Name 11").Visible = False
        .PivotItems("Name 12").Visible = False
        .PivotItems("Name 13").Visible = False
        .PivotItems("Name 14").Visible = False
        .PivotItems("Name 15").Visible = False
        .PivotItems("Name 16").Visible = False
        .PivotItems("Name 17").Visible = False
        .PivotItems("Name 18").Visible = False
        .PivotItems("Name 19").Visible = False
        .PivotItems("Name 20").Visible = False
        .PivotItems("Name 21").Visible = False
        .PivotItems("(blank)").Visible = False
    End With
    ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable4").PivotFields("MD").CurrentPage = "(All)"
    With ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable4").PivotFields("MD")
        .PivotItems("Name 1").Visible = False
        .PivotItems("Name 2").Visible = False
        .PivotItems("Name 3").Visible = False
        .PivotItems("Name 4").Visible = False
        .PivotItems("Name 5").Visible = False
        .PivotItems("Name 6").Visible = False
        .PivotItems("Name 7").Visible = False
        .PivotItems("Name 8").Visible = False
        .PivotItems("Name 9").Visible = False
        .PivotItems("Name 10").Visible = False
        .PivotItems("Name 11").Visible = False
        .PivotItems("Name 12").Visible = False
        .PivotItems("Name 13").Visible = False
        .PivotItems("Name 14").Visible = False
        .PivotItems("Name 15").Visible = False
        .PivotItems("Name 16").Visible = False
        .PivotItems("Name 17").Visible = False
        .PivotItems("Name 18").Visible = False
        .PivotItems("Name 19").Visible = False
        .PivotItems("Name 20").Visible = False
        .PivotItems("Name 21").Visible = False
        .PivotItems("(blank)").Visible = False
    End With
    ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable1").PivotFields("MD").CurrentPage = "(All)"
    With ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable1").PivotFields("MD")
        .PivotItems("Name 1").Visible = False
        .PivotItems("Name 2").Visible = False
        .PivotItems("Name 3").Visible = False
        .PivotItems("Name 4").Visible = False
        .PivotItems("Name 5").Visible = False
        .PivotItems("Name 6").Visible = False
        .PivotItems("Name 7").Visible = False
        .PivotItems("Name 8").Visible = False
        .PivotItems("Name 9").Visible = False
        .PivotItems("Name 10").Visible = False
        .PivotItems("Name 11").Visible = False
        .PivotItems("Name 12").Visible = False
        .PivotItems("Name 13").Visible = False
        .PivotItems("Name 14").Visible = False
        .PivotItems("Name 15").Visible = False
        .PivotItems("Name 16").Visible = False
        .PivotItems("Name 17").Visible = False
        .PivotItems("Name 18").Visible = False
        .PivotItems("Name 19").Visible = False
        .PivotItems("Name 20").Visible = False
        .PivotItems("Name 21").Visible = False
        .PivotItems("(blank)").Visible = False
    End With
    ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable5").PivotFields("MD").CurrentPage = "(All)"
    With ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable5").PivotFields("MD")
        .PivotItems("Name 1").Visible = False
        .PivotItems("Name 2").Visible = False
        .PivotItems("Name 3").Visible = False
        .PivotItems("Name 4").Visible = False
        .PivotItems("Name 5").Visible = False
        .PivotItems("Name 6").Visible = False
        .PivotItems("Name 7").Visible = False
        .PivotItems("Name 8").Visible = False
        .PivotItems("Name 9").Visible = False
        .PivotItems("Name 10").Visible = False
        .PivotItems("Name 11").Visible = False
        .PivotItems("Name 12").Visible = False
        .PivotItems("Name 13").Visible = False
        .PivotItems("Name 14").Visible = False
        .PivotItems("Name 15").Visible = False
        .PivotItems("Name 16").Visible = False
        .PivotItems("Name 17").Visible = False
        .PivotItems("Name 18").Visible = False
        .PivotItems("Name 19").Visible = False
        .PivotItems("Name 20").Visible = False
        .PivotItems("Name 21").Visible = False
        .PivotItems("(blank)").Visible = False
    End With
    ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable6").PivotFields("MD").CurrentPage = "(All)"
    With ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable6").PivotFields("MD")
        .PivotItems("Name 1").Visible = False
        .PivotItems("Name 2").Visible = False
        .PivotItems("Name 3").Visible = False
        .PivotItems("Name 4").Visible = False
        .PivotItems("Name 5").Visible = False
        .PivotItems("Name 6").Visible = False
        .PivotItems("Name 7").Visible = False
        .PivotItems("Name 8").Visible = False
        .PivotItems("Name 9").Visible = False
        .PivotItems("Name 10").Visible = False
        .PivotItems("Name 11").Visible = False
        .PivotItems("Name 12").Visible = False
        .PivotItems("Name 13").Visible = False
        .PivotItems("Name 14").Visible = False
        .PivotItems("Name 15").Visible = False
        .PivotItems("Name 16").Visible = False
        .PivotItems("Name 17").Visible = False
        .PivotItems("Name 18").Visible = False
        .PivotItems("Name 19").Visible = False
        .PivotItems("Name 20").Visible = False
        .PivotItems("Name 21").Visible = False
        .PivotItems("(blank)").Visible = False
    End With
    ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable7").PivotFields("MD").CurrentPage = "(All)"
    With ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable7").PivotFields("MD")
        .PivotItems("Name 1").Visible = False
        .PivotItems("Name 2").Visible = False
        .PivotItems("Name 3").Visible = False
        .PivotItems("Name 4").Visible = False
        .PivotItems("Name 5").Visible = False
        .PivotItems("Name 6").Visible = False
        .PivotItems("Name 7").Visible = False
        .PivotItems("Name 8").Visible = False
        .PivotItems("Name 9").Visible = False
        .PivotItems("Name 10").Visible = False
        .PivotItems("Name 11").Visible = False
        .PivotItems("Name 12").Visible = False
        .PivotItems("Name 13").Visible = False
        .PivotItems("Name 14").Visible = False
        .PivotItems("Name 15").Visible = False
        .PivotItems("Name 16").Visible = False
        .PivotItems("Name 17").Visible = False
        .PivotItems("Name 18").Visible = False
        .PivotItems("Name 19").Visible = False
        .PivotItems("Name 20").Visible = False
        .PivotItems("Name 21").Visible = False
        .PivotItems("(blank)").Visible = False
    End With
    ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable8").PivotFields("MD").CurrentPage = "(All)"
    With ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable8").PivotFields("MD")
        .PivotItems("Name 1").Visible = False
        .PivotItems("Name 2").Visible = False
        .PivotItems("Name 3").Visible = False
        .PivotItems("Name 4").Visible = False
        .PivotItems("Name 5").Visible = False
        .PivotItems("Name 6").Visible = False
        .PivotItems("Name 7").Visible = False
        .PivotItems("Name 8").Visible = False
        .PivotItems("Name 9").Visible = False
        .PivotItems("Name 10").Visible = False
        .PivotItems("Name 11").Visible = False
        .PivotItems("Name 12").Visible = False
        .PivotItems("Name 13").Visible = False
        .PivotItems("Name 14").Visible = False
        .PivotItems("Name 15").Visible = False
        .PivotItems("Name 16").Visible = False
        .PivotItems("Name 17").Visible = False
        .PivotItems("Name 18").Visible = False
        .PivotItems("Name 19").Visible = False
        .PivotItems("Name 20").Visible = False
        .PivotItems("Name 21").Visible = False
        .PivotItems("(blank)").Visible = False
    End With
    ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable9").PivotFields("MD").CurrentPage = "(All)"
    With ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable9").PivotFields("MD")
        .PivotItems("Name 1").Visible = False
        .PivotItems("Name 2").Visible = False
        .PivotItems("Name 3").Visible = False
        .PivotItems("Name 4").Visible = False
        .PivotItems("Name 5").Visible = False
        .PivotItems("Name 6").Visible = False
        .PivotItems("Name 7").Visible = False
        .PivotItems("Name 8").Visible = False
        .PivotItems("Name 9").Visible = False
        .PivotItems("Name 10").Visible = False
        .PivotItems("Name 11").Visible = False
        .PivotItems("Name 12").Visible = False
        .PivotItems("Name 13").Visible = False
        .PivotItems("Name 14").Visible = False
        .PivotItems("Name 15").Visible = False
        .PivotItems("Name 16").Visible = False
        .PivotItems("Name 17").Visible = False
        .PivotItems("Name 18").Visible = False
        .PivotItems("Name 19").Visible = False
        .PivotItems("Name 20").Visible = False
        .PivotItems("Name 21").Visible = False
        .PivotItems("(blank)").Visible = False
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: I would think recording the macro would be the best option. I don't think the code for the recorded macro would use slower commands - so there might be some other reason it is getting slowed down for you.

Comment: Try turning off screenupdating then setting it back on after changing the 8 pivots...

Comment: Setting `Application.ScreenUpdating` will most likely help a lot (and be sufficient for you)! However, if it is still too slow, its possible the recorded macro is running some inefficient code. If you want to edit your post with the code you have, we may be able to edit it down a bit to help.

Comment: Well, the Application.ScreenUpdating certainly helped the speed - thank you for that! However, I've run into an error that I THINK is being caused by the filters not being set to what they were originally set to when I recorded the macro. I'll edit my post to include the code for the macro. Thanks for the help by the way guys.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's a lot of code.  Refactoring might make it easier to spot the problem:

```
Sub Filter_Foot()

    Dim pt As PivotTables
    Set pt = ActiveSheet.PivotTables

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    SetPF pt("PivotTable3").PivotFields("MD")
    SetPF pt("PivotTable2").PivotFields("MD")
    SetPF pt("PivotTable4").PivotFields("MD")
    SetPF pt("PivotTable1").PivotFields("MD")
    SetPF pt("PivotTable5").PivotFields("MD")
    SetPF pt("PivotTable6").PivotFields("MD")
    SetPF pt("PivotTable7").PivotFields("MD")
    SetPF pt("PivotTable8").PivotFields("MD")
    SetPF pt("PivotTable9").PivotFields("MD")

    Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub

Sub SetPF(pf As PivotField)
    Dim i As Integer
    With pf
        .CurrentPage = "(All)"
        For i = 1 To 21
            .PivotItems("Name " & i).Visible = False
        Next i
        .PivotItems("(blank)").Visible = False
    End With
End Sub
```